# Is there any example of a group in $C[0,1]$ bounded by a specific norm?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

If we are working on $C[0,1]$ (the real-valued functions in $[0,1]$). Is there any example of a group in $C[0,1]$ such that the group is bounded with the norm $\lVert f \rVert _1=\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$ but it is not bounded with the $$\lVert f \rVert_\infty=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|\quad ?$$

Comment: Do you mean an additive subgroup? Because to me all additive subgroups of $C[0,1]$ except $\{0\}$ are unbounded, whatever the norm.

Comment: I believe no nontrivial group $G$ is bounded w.r.t. any norm $\|\cdot\|$ since if $f \in G, f \ne 0$ then for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$ we have $nf \in G$ and $\|nf\| = n\|f\| \to +\infty$.

Comment: The formulation of the above question is far from clear. Please, spell out more details, whatever you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not.

Suppose that $G$ is  a group which is not bounded in the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm. Then there is an element $f$ such that $|f(x_0)|>1$ for a point $x_0\in [0,1]$. By continuity, there are $\delta>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
|f(x)|>1+\varepsilon\quad \forall x\in[x_0-\delta,\,x_0+\delta]\cap [0,1]
$$
Now, $f^n(x)\in G$ for any $n$. Since
$$
|f(x)|>1+n\varepsilon \quad \forall x\in[x_0-\delta,\,x_0+\delta]\cap [0,1]
$$
you have
$$ 
\int_0^1 |f^n(t)|\, dt\ge \delta(1+n\varepsilon).
$$
Therefore $G$ is unbounded also for the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot.